# Matomo Tracking issue

Tags: https, tracking, matomo

This email is with respect to Matomo tracking of website. We have setup Matomo on our internal server and the Matomo is able to track the site when the site is browsed inside the server where Matomo is located, But it is unable to track the site when it is browsed outside the server where Matomo is not located. So could you please confirm if the Matomo can still track the site if it is browsed in that way.

Thanks,
Akhil Ch

Setup Matomo on WAMP.
Follow few steps suggested by Chat GPT.
Apache host files have edited.
SSL certificate has been setup on the server where matomo is setup.

NOTE: When tried to run the website with https:// inside the server where matomo is hosted, the site is working fine. But when we try to browse the same website ( https://matomo..includes our domain), it is not working. I'm getting forbidden and don't have permissions.